# Backbone.Marionette Layouts and Navigation

Tags: backbone.js, layout, navigation, marionette, region

I run on some interesting issue during working with nested Layouts.
Lets go right to example. A index.html have just one region:

```
...  
<div id="screen" />  
...
```

Now I have a login view which render on this region. When I succeed login I present home page(within ApplicaitonLayout) which contains so statistics. ApplicationLayout looks like this

```
<div id="screen">  
  <header />
  <nav id="menu" />
  <section id="content"/>
  <footer />
</div>
```

what I do here is render ApplicationLayout in screen region. Important thing here is that I want home navigation to be routable. I omit a lot of JS/Marionette code but basically I have something like that(base on Brain Mann style)

```
var applicationLayout = ApplicationLayout();

var navigation = {
  goHome: {
     new MenuController({region: applicationRegion.menu});
     new HomeController({region: applicationRegion.content});
  } 

}
app.screen.show(applicaitonLayout);
new HomeRoute(controller: navigation);
```

So what I do here is I ALWAYS need to render menu even if I don't need that for example someone click different menu option and only applicationRegion.content should be rerendered.
To be more general how to handle region which are partially static (After login menu always will be displayed) when navigation change?

**Edit:**

So the question is: Should I need always render menu on every change in menu navigation, even this menu is already there?
To be more specific we have 2 ways to reach home page:
- 1st route from browser, in which we would like to render whole home page(include menu)
- 2nd Navigate from menu item, in this case we should NOT need to render menu, because it should be there already.

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose, use an application region: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md

Your menu would be displayed in a region, and the main content (which can contain layouts) would be in another region.

You can see an example (from my [book on marionette](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction)) here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/app.js#L3

And a live example here: http://davidsulc.github.io/marionette-gentle-introduction/#contacts

Edit based on comments:

If your layout has been rendered (and therefore the menu is visible), you only need to change the layout's subview when a menu item is clicked: `myLayout.show(newView)`.

The communication can be handled through reqres, see for example https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/header/list/list_controller.js#L11 (event trigger) and https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/contacts_app.js#L27 (event handler)

Comment: David you suggest to make menu a application region. I dont want to do that. My application region is just #screen, and to this region I add ApplicationLayout which contains menu. How to handle use case when I switch menu navigation from home to profile for example, and NOT to always render menu region?

Comment: I don't want to menu be a application region because this imply that it will be present on website from the start of application . I want menu be a part of  ApplicationLayout which is shown after user successfully authenticated. Maybe I missing some concepts or I do something wrong in architecture level?

Comment: Then, what you need to do is when a use clicks on a menu option, you create a new view, and show it in the layout region. That's all...

Comment: So I need always render menu on every change in menu navigation, even this menu is already there? To be more specific we have 2 ways to reach home page: 1st route from browser, and 2nd from menu item. What I think there is no need to render menu in 2nd case(because it should be there) but I dont know how to enforce to NOT render menu  in second use case.

Comment: I've updated my answer: basically, you only need to update the layout's subview (no need to touch the menu).